# How can I define this kind of functions? $.get("path", function(data, status){ });

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need an example. How data is fetching from URL/path and how it is passing data into an anonymous function as an argument, how the code is executing whatever we are writing in that anonymous function.

Give an example with steps

Comment: why not read the jquery source of `$.get`?

Comment: First read about xmlhttprequest.  http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: $ maps to JQuery. Then in the function get of jQuery object you are passing  a string "path" and a function which in turn receives two argument - data and status.

Comment: anybody write a code which behaves same. suppose taking two arguments say var1, callback function. divide var1 with some value and send it back to callback function.

Comment: @DelightedD0D not a homework. For knowledge purpose. I'm a JavaScript developer, most of the time I'm using this kind of functions e.g. in node js we have similar function app.get('route', function(req, res){ } ); , I'm eager to know about it's syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called a callback function. It is passed as a parameter to the $.get function and it is called from inside that function with specific parameters. See example below:

```
function test(param1, callbackFunction) {
    if(param1) {
        var a = 1, b = 2;
        callbackFunction(a, b); // this is a call on the callbackFunction method received as parameter
    }
}

test(true, function(x, y) {
    console.log(x, y); // 1,2
});
```

Comment: yes, I really wants this.

Answer (score 1):

Functions can be passed as an argument, and the receiving function can execute it by using the `()` after the argument name. Example:

```
function process(callback){
    // do something - could be async or not, doesn't matter, then execute the callback, passing arguments
    callback('something', 1, false);
}

process(function(firstArg, secondArg, thirdArg){
    console.log( "called" );
    console.log( firstArg );
    console.log( secondArg );
    console.log( thirdArg );
});
```

Fetching data from a URL is done via the [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), but it doesn't matter what the function is doing, the basic process of passing callbacks and executing them is the same.